# How can I can I cash American checks when living in the Netherlands?

Tags: united-states, irs, non-resident, covid-19, stimulus

My wife and me have worked in the USA from 1968 until 1978 we are Dutch citizens and receive every month retirement payments in our Dutch bank account. We received $600 and $1400 stimulus checks each but we cannot cash them here in Europe.
Does anybody know how we can cash these checks?

Comment: My two german banks accept US$ checks (for a fee of course). Did you try some other banks?

Comment: I have done this in Asia and also know someone who has done it in the UK. In Asia most banks will take this check, but in the UK only some banks do. Maybe there are other Dutch banks that might accept this check?

Comment: Perhaps try a US bank that has a presence in the Netherlands like Citibank. (I have 2 of their creditcards, no other affiliation.)